# Monkeyrunner activity

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I have one problem, I has started 2 activities via `monkeyrunner`.
How I can close one of them?
I try to used `device.stopActivity(package/activity)`, but monkeyrunner have not these command.
And also i want to recieve all working activities how i can do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, Android manages the activities on his own. But there's a way to stop the activities via the kill command. Use a python script to do this:

First, simulate the touch of the home button:

```
device.press('KEYCODE_HOME', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

Then use the ps command to list the open processes:

```
processes = str(device.shell('ps'))
```

Then look in the processes variable to see if you package is still there. If it's there, find the line which contains the package and retrieve it's PID. Then use the PID to kill the process:

```
if package in processes:
    for line in processes.splitlines():
        if package in line:
            pid = line.split()[1]
device.shell('kill ' + pid)
```

Later edit:
I have found another way in which you can close/ stop a package:

```
device.shell('am force-stop package')
```

The am force-stop command needs the package name only as an argument. It closes the respective package.

Answer (score 0):

Hi better option is to stop the process

```
device.press('KEYCODE_HOME', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
kill_command = 'am force-stop %s' % package_name
device.shell(kill_command)
```